# Align one word to left & one word to right in SELECT OPTION

Tags: html, css

I am filling data in Select Option from c# code by merging two words. Now I want one word as left align & another as right. How to do that?

I want output like below:

```
MD1        LAPTOP
MD2        MOUSE
MD311      KEY-BOARD
MD45       HARD DISK
```

**or**

```
MD1           LAPTOP
MD2            MOUSE
MD311      KEY-BOARD
MD45       HARD DISK
```

**Note: I need list SELECT OPTION just because by clicking on the Item I want to display details of selected OPTION ITEM.**

Comment: from your desired output, looks like you just need to put equal spaces between your 2 words as the second word is tabbed not right aligned.

Comment: @Tanner, I know that trick but I want to bifurcate by alignment.

Comment: I don't think this is possible inside a select. You can technically still create your own 'dropdown' thing, which allows you to do whichever formatting you want.

Comment: This might not be the best solution. But as a option element cannot have a markup inside it, you might want to use HTML entities for this : http://jsfiddle.net/tT7Yq/

Comment: You can do this by adding some space between two text as @nkmol answered. Or you can create it by div. Create a design like listbox. Onclick show/hide the div.

Comment: Simple Answer: Not Possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try `word-spacing`:

```
<select name="mySelect">
    <option value="1">MD1 LAPTOP</option>
    <option value="2">MD2 MOUSE</option>
    <option value="3">MD3 KEY-BOARD</option>
    <option value="4">MD4 HARD DISK</option>
</select>

...

select, option {
    word-spacing:20px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ck9d8/1/

Comment: But what in case of MD55?

Comment: I think this is the solution to go. Now you might not be satisfied with the word "HARD DISK" be so far apart from each other. You can simply bypass tge 'word-spacing' with a 'fake' space entity; `&#8201;`. You might also only want to show the extra information on the option elements. Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/Ck9d8/2/

Comment: @DKS http://jsfiddle.net/Ck9d8/3/ With a 3 digit number you want to add a new bypasser. However i would suggest you to look for a better supported solution as this is actually not supported.

Comment: You won't find a perfect solution unless you go through Javascript to manipulate the text, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can put each word into a container, wether it's a div or a spain and put some classes in them to handle them with CSS. The simplest way to do this is by assigning a prefixed width to the left span. For example:

```
HTML:
<span class="left">MD1</span><span class="right">LAPTOP</span><br/>
<span class="left">MD2</span><span class="right">LAPTOP</span><br/>
<span class="left">MD3</span><span class="right">LAPTOP</span><br/>
<span class="left">MD4</span><span class="right">LAPTOP</span><br/>
<span class="left">MD5</span><span class="right">LAPTOP</span><br/>

CSS:
.left{
     display:inline-block;
     width: 100px;
}
```

A working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f7J8k/

You can also do it with display:table on a container div and display:table-row and display:table-cell for each "row" and "cell" and then set the space between cells, this will allow you to have a more flexible layout, but it's more complicated.

Or, since it's tabular data, just use a table.

Comment: I need to use SELECT OPTION just because by selecting on single option item, its related details will be displayed.

Comment: Then this is not possible. Options cannot have HTML inside of them and style them properly. You'll need to hack some ul>li*n into a select styling and handling click with jQuery (http://jsfiddle.net/f7J8k/1/) or use HTML entities, as noted by @nkmol.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use required space between your option value like;

```
<select>
    <option>MD1 &nbsp;&nbsp; LAPTOP</option>
    <option>MD2 &nbsp;&nbsp; MOUSE</option>
    <option>MD3 &nbsp;&nbsp; KEY-BOARD</option>
    <option>MD4 &nbsp;&nbsp; HARD DISK</option>
</select>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/f7J8k/2/

Comment: @DKS The same thing can achieved by adding container and applying classes over it, because this is the simplest work-arround.